# codeigniter routes issue for main url

Tags: php, oop, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I have defined a new route on routes.php but it have problem.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "index";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(:any)'] = "oyna/oyun/$1";
```

I want to redirect /2012.htm to oyna/oyun/2012.htm and I can but it create a new problem. I can't reach my other controller if I don't define as below:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "index";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['admin/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'admin/$1/$2';
$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin/$1';
$route['kategori/(:any)'] = "oyna/kategori/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "oyna/oyun/$1";
```

If i don't define any controllers on routes.php like above I can't reach that.
What i need to do for solve?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but try to replace `$route['(:any)'] = "oyna/oyun/$1";` with `$route['(:num).htm'] = "oyna/oyun/$1.htm";`

Or better: `$route['(\d+).htm'] = "oyna/oyun/$1.htm";`

Comment: But I need to use (:any) for SEO.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter's routes are a little funny, but once you understand how they're processed, it makes perfect sense.

Since routes use regular expression matching, you can't just have something super generic and expect everything else to work, because it's going to look at routes before simply routing to the controller/method implied by the URL.

If you want to match URLs such as `http://domain.tld/2njkf4r` AND `http://domain.tld/pages/about` then you will have to create more specific rules to handle "exceptions" to the very general rule that will match the first case.

You are correct that it won't work unless you define the other routes, because with only `$route['(:any)']` as a route, EVERY request will match that. That route has to be your absolute last route. It's a pain in the ass, but necessary, because of the way they process routes.

Comment: in fact i have a idea, if "/" typed it mean this is not for /oyna/oyun /. If "/" not typed it mean this is controller, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment... could you rephrase?

Comment: my oyna/oyun/'s urls haven't got "/" key. if "/" typed this mean it is controller. :)

Comment: I see, no, that's not how that works. The value of each route defines "controller/method/{args}" where {args} can be any number of arguments passed to the controller method. After reviewing how you're using routes, I think an .htaccess rule (assuming Apache) would suit you better. Routes are meant for routing URL patterns to controllers, not physical files.

Answer (score 0):

My all links have .htm at end's. And this is the solve:

```
$route['(:any).htm'] = "oyna/oyun/$1";
```

Because my controllers haven't got .htm at the end.